# Advanced python for loop understanding

Tags: python

I once copied a line of code from stackoverflow:

```
clusters = [x for n, x in enumerate(vecarray) if x not in vecarray[:n]]
```

I understand what it does, but not how. It gives me all the unique rows of the array '`vecarray`' and saves them in '`clusters`'. I do have basic understanding of normal for loops, but this structure looks different.

How would I edit this line of code, if I also want to save the indices the found rows (basically in what row did the loop find the next unique number)

Can someone shed light on it?

Comment: Please update the question with some sample data, the result of `clusters` and what you would like to see changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop format in Python is called [loop comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), is an alternative and compact way to create lists in Python.

About your question you can keep the indices with multiple ways, it depends with what you want

#### Approach 1:

```
clusters = [{'idx':n, 'value':x} for n, x in enumerate(vecarray) if x not in vecarray[:n]]
```

**Example:**

```
#Dummy input
vecarray=[1,2,1,2,3,4]

clusters = [{'idx':n, 'value':x} for n, x in enumerate(vecarray) if x not in  vecarray[:n]]

print(clusters)

#Result
[{'idx': 0, 'value': 1}, {'idx': 1, 'value': 2}, {'idx': 4, 'value': 3},{'idx': 5, 'value': 4}]
```

#### Approach 2:

Replace list comprehension with dict comprehension

```
clusters = { str(n): x for n, x in enumerate(vecarray) if x not in vecarray[:n]}
```

**Example:**

```
#Dummy input
vecarray=[1,2,1,2,3,4]

clusters = {str(n): x for n, x in enumerate(vecarray) if x not in vecarray[:n]}

print(clusters)

#Result
{'0': 1, '1': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `enumerate()` function is already returning you the row the value was found in as n.

If you simply change your code to:

```
clusters = [(n, x) for n, x in enumerate(vecarray) if x not in vecarray[:n]]
```

Then you should have a list of tuples, instead of a list of values.

You can then do:

```
for n,x in clusters:
    print(x," found at row ",n)
```

Your line of code is a list comprehension. You can re-write it to be a standard for loop instead:

```
clusters=[]
for n,x in enumerate(vecarray):
    if x not in vecarray[:n]:
        clusters.append((n,x))
```